# I can't use the "print/println" functions

Tags: java

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.
I've done all that my Googling has provided me with as potential solutions.
I've tried doing the File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart, it still doesn't fix it.

This is the entire code;
This was copied from the OCI documentation, and I've already made some amendments to the code, but I don't know how to fix this.
I'm a junior yes, but am I wrong to be annoyed over how much of the documentation through the use of which I'm to be developing myself has these kinds of issues..

This is the entire code.

```
package com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile.printUsage;


public class ociAuth {
    private static String server;
    private static String user;
    private static String password;
    private static String port = "8443";
    private static String response_format = "json";
    private static String server_url;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length < 3 || args.length > 4) {
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        setUserArguments(args);
        server_url = "https://" + server + ":" + port + "/rest/v1/assets/storages";
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection connection =
                    getAllTrustingHttpsUrlConnection();
            if(connection == null) {
                System.err.println("FATAL: Failed to create HTTPS connection to URL: " + server_url);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("Invoking API: " + server_url);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/" + response_format);
            String authString = getAuthorizationString();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
                    authString);
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.err.println("API Invocation Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + connection.getResponseCode());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (connection.getInputStream())));
            String response;
            System.out.println("Response:");
            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(response);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW
//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW
//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW

            System.out.print("\nUsage:\n\tHelloApiServices <api-server host[:port]> <user> <password> [json|xml]\n");
            System.out.print("\nExamples:\n\tHelloApiServices localhost admin mypassword");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34:8320 admin password");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34 admin password xml");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34:8212 admin password xml\n");
            System.out.print("\nNote:\n\t(1) When port number is not provided, 8443 is chosen by default.");
            System.out.print("\t(2) When response format (json or xml) is not provided, json is chosen by default. \n");
}

//THESE PRINTS HERE ABOVE
//THESE PRINTS HERE ABOVE
//THESE PRINTS HERE ABOVE

    private static void setUserArguments(String[] args) {
        server = args[0];
        user = args[1];
        password = args[2];
        if(args.length == 4) {
            response_format = args[3];
            if(!response_format.equals("json") && ! response_format.equals("xml")) {
                        printUsage();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        if(server.contains(":")) {
            String[] parts = server.split(":");
            server = parts[0];
            port = parts[1];
        }
    }

    private static HttpsURLConnection getAllTrustingHttpsUrlConnection() {
        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCertificatesManager = new
                    TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return
                            null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[]
                                                       certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[]
                                                       certs, String authType) {
                }
            }};

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCertificatesManager, new
                    SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            URL url = new URL(server_url);
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession
                        session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
    private static String getAuthorizationString() {
        String userPassword = user + ":" + password;
        byte[] authEncodedBytes =
                Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes());
        String ajdeovako = new String(authEncodedBytes);
        return ajdeovako;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the IDE to auto-format your code, my bet is the brackets are unbalanced and you're attempting to print outside of a method (on windows: ctrl + alt + L)

Comment: why import static java.lang.System.out ?

Comment: @Rogue is right - your print statements are out of any method.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket. The System.out.print calls are not inside you `main` method, but are instead between methods and the closing bracket after the print calls shouldn't be there. Move the print calls up inside your main method and it should compile fine.

Comment: Thank you, I won't try to explain how this was overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `}`, removing it will fix your error.

```
    } <-- remove this

//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW
//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW
//THESE PRINTS HERE BELLOW

            System.out.print("\nUsage:\n\tHelloApiServices <api-server host[:port]> <user> <password> [json|xml]\n");
            System.out.print("\nExamples:\n\tHelloApiServices localhost admin mypassword");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34:8320 admin password");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34 admin password xml");
            System.out.print("\tHelloApiServices 10.22.12.34:8212 admin password xml\n");
            System.out.print("\nNote:\n\t(1) When port number is not provided, 8443 is chosen by default.");
            System.out.print("\t(2) When response format (json or xml) is not provided, json is chosen by default. \n");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to say. I can't believe that this is what it's come down to.
Thank you, I'll walk away in shame now.

Comment: No shame in it at all, this is just why people use things like auto-formatters. It makes these kinds of errors more obvious.